# Laravel echo listens multiple times

Tags: laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I have created a simple chat app wherein a user may send a message privately. Now, while the page is on first load (mounted), the console logs only one line. If I click on other links (not hard refresh) and go back to the page, the console logs multiple times.

Using ReactJS

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.Echo.private(`chat`).listen('PrivateMessageEvent', e => { 
    console.log(e) // this logs multiple times
   });
}, []);
```

If using VueJS

```
mounted() {
   window.Echo.private(`chat`).listen('PrivateMessageEvent', e => { 
    console.log(e) // this logs multiple times
   });
}
```

Example:

When I visit page `/first-link`, this logs only one line.

Then, if go to `/second-link` (`<router-link> for vuejs` / `<Link /> for reactjs`) , then `/third-link` and go back to `/first-link`, the console logs multiple times.

I notice that the Echo listens multiple times. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

This issue occurs when a component is re-rendered when visiting other routes.

**Solution**

When I put the `window.Echo` on child component, the Echo listens many times based on the number of visits. That's why, I put it at the uppermost / parent component so that it won't re-render the component.

As much as possible, I put it at the _app.js level.

Comment: can you share where did you put the onmounted event? Tried your approach and it seems the page wont load on my case.

Comment: can you explain how you fixed your problem. I have an issue where when I put it at the app.js level, it fires before use has logged in so does not connect and then does not connect after login.